# Laravel BelongsTo for 2 different tables with same field

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, relationship

I have a database scenario with the following tables: (I using Laravel 5.2)

Class A: id, student_name, address

(for example: 1, Karthik, Chennai)

Class B: id, student_name, address
(for example: 1, Kumar, Chennai)

Fees: id, student_id, Class_id (A or B)

When I list fees it will display both A and B class students (where they have the same roll no as they are different sections)

I want to display if it is A class it will be showing A class Student, Otherwise B.

How could I achieve this result?

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 different tables, you need to create 2 methods inside your Fees model, with

```
    public static function classA()                                         
{
return Self::class->where('class_id', 'A');
}
```

And, in your controller, you can use

```
$class_a=Fees::classA()->get();
```

Same for every class.

Note that your scenario isn't good at all, you don't have to make different table for each class, you just need to create a Class table, and add `class_id` into student table, and if a student can access different classes, you need to make a pivot table.

Comment: I just gave a student datable as a sample with the same scenario in my project.

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you mean, but feel free to try my simple solution above, I'll be happy to help.

Comment: It throws this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR), expecting ';' (for your information i using laravel 5.2)

Comment: Yeah, man @didenetahi! you are right about the note part.